# Accessing Secured Webservice via mobilefirst adapter

Tags: ssl, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

i need to access a wsdl which is secured i.e **https and need certificates etc to access**.What i did his i followed the steps specified here instead of directly downloading certificates from browser: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_configuring_SSL_WL_adapters_backend_servers_certificates.html

when i do the last step **keytool -v -list -keystore mfp-default.keystore** i get

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: backend
Creation date: 5 Feb, 2016
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

my doubt is whether what i have done is enough to access a secured https and do i need anything to add here below for sslcert and ssl pass in adapter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
    5725-I43 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2011, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
    US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
    disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
-->
<wl:adapter name="cloudcheck"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:wl="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration"
    xmlns:http="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration/http">

    <displayName>cloudcheck</displayName>
    <description>cloudcheck</description>
    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
            <protocol>https</protocol>
            <domain>mydummy.com</domain>
            <port>443</port>
            <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>50</maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>
            <!-- Following properties used by adapter's key manager for choosing specific certificate from key store  
            <sslCertificateAlias>backend</sslCertificateAlias> 
            <sslCertificatePassword>password</sslCertificatePassword>
            -->     
        </connectionPolicy>
    </connectivity>

    <procedure name="getFeed"/>

</wl:adapter>
```

Comment: Hello, is it working for you ? From my side I exported my SSL certificate from Firefox, then imported it into the project keystore, but I am still having an javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException exception. Have you solved the issue from your side ? if yes, can you share the solution or any hint ?

Comment: @hume, any updates to this question?